# Node typescript global service to return value from a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, global

I'm trying to implement a service for my backend that allows the session data to be called from anywhere in the code, which means I want to create a service file that exports the values from the functions that get the session data. Otherwise I can only get the session data from inside functions that have both req: Request and res: Response parameters. So I'm basically trying to lock the values to a variable that can be used and called from anywhere in my project. My code now looks like this but if I use the exports anywhere else in the file, it just prints the actual code (function) snippet instead of the return value specified inside the code. I'm pretty new to typescript and node in general which means I might be doing some really silly errors here.

Thanks for all the help in advance!
/Victor

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

function getUserSessionData(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const userData = res.status(200).send(req.session.userData);
    return userData;
}
function getUserSessionLang(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const userLang = res.status(200).send(req.session.language);
   return userLang;
}
function getUserSessionAll(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const userAll = res.status(200).send(req.session);
   return userAll;
}


module.exports = {
    userData: getUserSessionData,
    userLang: getUserSessionLang,
    userAll: getUserSessionAll
};
```

How I would like it to work:

```
const sessionService = require("./services/sessionService");
function getStuff(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    let redisKey;
    if (!req.session.language) {
         redisKey = "getStuffEN";
    }
    else {
         redisKey = "getStuff" + sessionService.userLang;
    }
    console.log(redisKey);
    getRedis(redisKey, function success(reply: any) {
        res.status(200).json(
            JSON.parse(reply)
        );
}, function error(err: Error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong");
});
}
```

This is how it is right now (and working)

```
function getStuff(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    let redisKey;
    if (!req.session.language) {
         redisKey = "getStuffEN";
    }
    else {
         redisKey = "getStuff" + req.session.language;
    }
    console.log(redisKey);
    getRedis(redisKey, function success(reply: any) {
        res.status(200).json(
            JSON.parse(reply)
        );
}, function error(err: Error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong");
});
}
```

I want it to work like the first example, since there are some instances in my code where I want to access the data without having to pass the req, res parameters, if possible.

Comment: write the data to a db or to a file

Comment: But the data is modified on the fly, since the cookies are only stored for either the session duration or max 1 day. It feels abit risky security wise to store the data anywhere else, because then the userdata is stored somewhere and might get exposed to external threats.

Comment: so clear data once the session termantes

Comment: *It feels abit risky security wise* - if a database has a chance to be exposed, that's what's risky. Are you going to store all sensitive user data in RAM because of security concerns?

Comment: Right now I implemented a redisstore actually so that the data is stored somewhere, but to access the data I still have to use req.session which means that it needs to be inside a function with a req: Request parameter. I'm still just having troubles to find a way to bypass this. The redisstore generates a random key for each session, but it feels kinda overkill to save that key somewhere and then use the client.get redis function to access the session data, because then I would have to save the randomly generated key somewhere and match it with the session, no?

Comment: @madvic how are you using the exported functions? Add that snippet to your question please.

Comment: Also, are you using a middleware for creating the session or are you doing it yourself?

Comment: @LukasKnuth Added some examples, thanks a lot for the help!

Im using express-session for creating the sessions and redisstore (connect-redis) to store the session data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a short explanation on sessions:

- When a user logs in (and you verify his credentials, etz) you start a new session for that user.
- The middleware you're using will assign this session a unique ID and you can assign some data to it.

  - The *ID* is transferred to the users Browser in form of a cookie
  - The *Data* is stored on the Server (in Redis for your case)
- The middleware will check if a session-cookie with a valid ID is included in a request and do the following:

  - Fetch Session-*Data* for the given *ID* from Redis
  - Populate the `req.session`-object with the *Data* from Redis
  - Call the next Route

---

With this out of the way, a word of advice: Don't store the session-data in your applications memory. Why? The data should only be relevant in the context of a request from a user. You'll need the session data to handle the request, but you don't need it otherwise.

Instead of storing it globally, build your handlers and functions to accept the specific Session-*Data* as parameters, like this:

```
// handler, after middleware:
const getUserBio = (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.session.userId;
    const bioData = fetchBio(userId);
    res.render("userBio", bioData);
}

// somewhere else in your code
function fetchBio(userId) {
    const fullBio = database.fetchBio(userId);
    return {
        full: fullBio,
        excerpt: fullBio.substring(0, 24);
    }
}
```

This has two important advantages:

1. You don't have to keep the session-*Data* in your memory synchronized with the one in Redis
2. These (almost) [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) make your code easier to understand

If you write functions that work entirely on their input parameters and don't use any global state, things like "order in which to call functions" or "check if data is available" become irrelevant. The caller is responsible for getting the data, the callee is responsible for working with it.

Extending on that, express routes should **never use any global in-memory data**, if you ever want to scale your application horizontally (by using multiple instances). It can't be guaranteed that the same client will always connect to the same server-instance, so the globally stored data might be available for one request but not for the next. In this case, you'll have to find a way to share the global data between all your instances, which is what Redis already does in your case.

---

**tl;dr:** Only access the session-data in a request-handler, then pass it on as parameters to any functions that need to work on it. Don't keep global in-memory state in your server if you ever want to scale it horizontally.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, greatly appreciated! So if I understood correctly, I can format all my fetches this way, and the (in this case) const getUserBio is then used anywhere in my code when I want to access the bioData. My follow up question is however that doesn't this mean that when I use the getUserBio const elsewhere, I still have to pass parameters? Or if I for example just use console.log(getUserBio) its not gonna print out the values that the function returns, am I correct?

Pardon if these questions seem silly, I'm quite new to node.js and javascript/typescript

/V

Comment: a) Yes, you're correct, you'll need to pass in the parameters every time. I hope it cam through in the answer but: There should be no reason to need the function anywhere else. Your entire application is basically "run code when user request comes in", so you'll not need the data if there isn't an associated user request.

Comment: b) If you print `console.log(getUserBio)`, that will print the string-representation of the function. To be clear, this **does not invoke** the function! Functions in JavaScript/TypeScript are primitives like `number` or `string`, so you can pass them as parameters and assign them to variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lukas!
This clears up a bunch of stuff I have been thinking about.
Just out of curiosity, if I wanted use the function without the parameters, is there any clean way to store the function return value to a variable or something similar that I can just call anywhere in my code without the parameters?
I've been wondering about this for a while and never really found a clear solution.

Thanks again for all your help!
/Victor

Comment: @madvic not sure if I understand. Why can't you assign the value returned by the function (called with parameters) to a variable? If you want to have this globally available, there is no good way to do it. Servers are different to client-applications in that you don't know if the next interaction is going to be the same person. So having state in-memory is usually a bad idea and leads to accidental data leaks (when you're showing data to the wrong user).

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of having it globally available, but as you say, its not a good idea. Your way seems much better and since my app is horizontally scalable I've come to understand that global variables are really bad (just as you say, because the interactions can get mixed up). Thanks for everything Lukas, I've learned a lot from this and know I know what to do and what not to do!

Thanks again and have a wonderful Christmas and a great new year!
Best regards,
/Victor

Answer (score 0):

You can write data to a db or to a file as it say madvic, but we can use also global variables. But global variables is a bad practise, as I know, so It's better to write someone your data.